# How to make file executable from context menu?

Tags: files, file-management, contract

I know this can be done under the file's Properties or with the command `sudo chmod a+x`.

But how to add it to context menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gedit ~/.local/share/contractor/make_executable.contract
```

with

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Make executable
MimeType=text/plain
Exec=pantheon-terminal -e 'sudo chmod a+x %f'
```

This form also works:

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Make executable
MimeType=text/plain
Exec=pkexec chmod a+x %f
Terminal=true
```